# Does my Homebrew work properly? Do you receive the message about "brewland"?

Tags: homebrew, macos-sierra

When I use the command "`brew doctor`", it says "Your system is ready to brew." But, then I use another command "`brew update`" and it starts updating. What about the phrase "You haven't updated for at least 24 hours. This is a long time in brewland"?

Why didn't I receive this message? Does it mean "`brew doctor`" not work properly? Besides a lack of message, everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you brew update it simply sets a time stamp of when that happened. If you then run `brew doctor` and the comparison of the time stamp and the current time is greater than 24 hours then it gives you the message of

> you haven't updated for at least 24 hours.

Brew doesn't check if there are updates to your installed packages in the background, you simply just need to run `brew update` every now and again.

Comment: The thing is when I start with "brew update", there is no way of displaying "You haven't updated for at least 24 hours." because I've just updated, therefore when I type "brew doctor", I will get "Your system is ready to brew." It looks like this message doesn't appear anymore. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems it doesn't work properly in my Terminal.

Comment: @zoe from what you're saying what your doing seems normal practice. If you are wanting to see the 24 hour message simply don't `brew update` first just run `brew doctor` when you last ran `brew update` over 24 hours prior. Generally using brew we only ever run `brew doctor` if there is an issue with brew itself or one of the packages.

Comment: I waited 3 days to get this message about "over 24 hours in brewland". The only one I received was "Your system is ready to brew." I had started with "brew doctor". Everything seems to be working fine, so I don't bother anymore. Thanks for your help :)